# Angular "module build failed"

Tags: angular, module-build

i've been trying for a while now but nothing seems to work.

The problem is as follow:

After project creation with `ng new <my-app>` and attempt to build or start it with `npm run start` or `npm run build` or `ng serve` -  I get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Dhqc.png)

This is my global angular [version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM8pf.png)

And this is the project's [package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBNPA.png)

Some of the things I've tried:

1 - delete node_modules and package-lock.json file and then run `npm cache clean --force` and then install the packages again with `npm install`

2 - delete global angular and installed it again with `npm install @angular/cli@latest` and then tried to create a new project with `ng new my-app>`

3 - tried to create in different directory the project.